# My app, that uses external dll conteined in an external directory, stop working when i shared that directory

Tags: c#, asp.net

I had a working app that uses some external dll´s, and that app stop working once i shared the folder in which those external dll´s where stored.

That folder is in a external path, not in the one that my code is located in the Visual Studio TFS system.

I try setting total control to all users to the folder once the references stop working but i haven´t had any luck,

i think its a problem that has to do with permissions or something that went bad after i shared the folder with other computer because until that moment everything worked ok.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry im kind of new on this... i just added again the reference Path to the project (in project properties) and  it worked.
Thanks.